# Minimum values of complex number $|z_1^3+z_2^3|$ if $|z_1+z_2|$ and $|z_1^2+z_2^2|$ are given

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two complex numbers such that $|z_1+z_2|=1$ and $|z_1^2+z_2^2|=25$, find the minimum value of $|z_1^3+z_2^3|$.

**My try:**

The minimum value is $37$ which I dot by taking $z_1+z_2=1$ and considering only real part and$z_1^2+z_2^2=25$, hence we get $z_1=4$ and $z_2=-3$, solving we get $|z_1^3+z_2^3|=|64-27|=37$

But this is not the appropriate way , it needs to be solved via triangle property or property of complex number, I am not able to solve it via property

Comment: A little observation: $$|z_1^2 + z_2^2| = |(z_1+z_2)^2 - 2z_1z_2| \le |z_1 + z_2|^2 + 2|z_1z_2|$$
This implies 
$$|z_1z_2| \ge 12$$

Comment: Also use $|z_1^3+z_2^3|$ = $|z_1+z_2||z_1^2+z_2^2 - z_1z_2|$

Comment: Nice, @eyllanesc and vivid. Hence,$$|z_1^3+z_2^3| = |(z_1+z_2)^2 - 3z_1z_2|\ge 3|z_1z_2| - |z_1+z_2|^2\ge 36-1 = 35.$$That's maybe not the solution, but it's getting close. In addition,$$25 = |2z_1z_2 - (z_1+z_2)^2|\ge 2|z_1z_2| - 1,$$ thus $|z_1z_2|\le 13$, so that $|z_1^3+z_2^3|\le 38$.

Comment: @eyllanesc But $35$ is a little better. ;-)

Comment: One more observation: by simultaneous rotation we may assume that one of the two numbers is real.

Comment: @eyllanesc $|z_1z_2| \ne 12$ but $\ge 12$

Comment: $$|z_1^3+z_2^3| = |z_1^2-z_1z_2 + z_2^2| = |\frac32(z_1^2+z_2^2)-\frac12(z_1+z_2)^2|\\ \ge \frac32|z_1^2+z_2^2|-\frac12|z_1+z_2|^2 = 37$$

Comment: @achillehui Isn't this actually an answer? $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is made of achille hui's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285604/minimum-values-of-complex-number-z-13z-23-if-z-1z-2-and-z-12z-2#comment8921346_4285604).*

---

Observe that
$$\begin{align}
|z_1^3+z_2^3| 
&= |z_1^2-z_1z_2 + z_2^2| \\
&= \left|\frac32(z_1^2+z_2^2)-\frac12(z_1+z_2)^2\right| \\
&\ge \frac32|z_1^2+z_2^2|-\frac12|z_1+z_2|^2 \\
&= 37 \end{align}$$
Also, note that the equality holds for $(z_1,z_2) = (4,-3)$. So, indeed, the minimum value of the required expression is $37$.